# Flow type inference not working

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following code:

```
export const notesService = {

   getChannelOptions(): ChannelOption[] {
      return [...channelOptions];
   },

   getChannelLabelFromValue(value: string): string {
      let x =this.getChannelOptions();
      x = x  + 3;
      const label = channelOptions.filter(co => co.value === value);
     return label[0] ? label[0].label : "";
   }

}
```

The question is what must I do that flow throws an error when I try to add 3 to an array.

BTW: it works if I declare getChannelOptions outside noteService as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved it using by explicitly declaring but there could be potentially a better approach

```
let x = notesService.getChannelOptions();
```